# How To save and load an Object using SharedPreferences

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences

So I have been trying to load all of my Recent Search history object using shared preferences.
and it doesn't work, it says that "List is not a subtype of List" the error code happens when I call the loadData function. I don't know why my code is not working.

So this is my shared preferences and method code:

```
void _addLastSearch(String hospitalId,String hospitalName)
  {
    final lastSearching=SearchModel(hospitalId: hospitalId,hospitalName: hospitalName);
    setState(() {
      recentSearch.add(lastSearching);
    });
  }

  void savedData() async  {
    SharedPreferences prefs= await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
   
    prefs.setString('data',jsonEncode(recentSearch));
  }
  void loadData()async{
    SharedPreferences prefs= await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    print("test masul load");
    
    recentSearch=jsonDecode(prefs.getString('data'));
  
      print(recentSearch.length);
  }
```

Comment: I think it is because of recentSearch variable being of type list. you could try jsonEncode on each SearchModel and create a list<String> out of it, then you can use prefs.setStringList("key", list); to store and prefs.getStringList("key"); to retrieve from shared_preferences

Comment: nevermind I found the solution :)),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

any im changin the load data function to:

recentSearch=(jsonDecode(prefs.getString('data'))).map((item)=>SearchModel.fromJson(item)).toList();